# Limit Troubles: Showing that the definition of $P(A|B)$ is consistent with the definition of probability as a relative frequency.

Tags: probability, limits

It is said that the definition of the probability of an event $A$ is given as 
$$P(A)=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(A)}{n}}$$

Where $n(A)$ is the number of times that the event $A$ occurs in $n$ tries. I wanted to show that 
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$$

is consistent with the definition above,

So I took it as true that $P(AB)=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(AB)}{n}}$ and $P(B)=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(A)}{n}}$.

I wanted to multiply both sided of these precedding two equation by $n$  to get $nP(AB)=n(AB)$  and $nP(B)=n(B)$, but I don't think that these two equations are true statements.

For instance with $nP(B)=n(B)$, if we consider the statement $5(B)$ we may or may not have equality $5P(B)$.

I think my problem is that I cannot cancel the limit on the RHS of the equations because it still applies to $n(B)$ right? But if that is the case then I have $nP(B)=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}n(B)$, does this imply that the limit is applying to both side of the equation? **I feel like I am breaking some limit rules here, and I couldn't find them in my calculus book.**

Comment: "I don't think that these two equations are true statements" Of course they are not, you just dropped the limit parts. Let $N_n(B)$ denote the number of times $B$ occurs in $n$ tries (a much better notation). Then $\frac1nN_n(B)$ converges (almost surely, and to $P(B)$) while $N_n(B)$ itself  goes to infinity (almost surely, as soon as $P(B)\ne0$). Compare with your post.

Comment: I won't address your question right now (maybe later), but I'd just like to mention: your use of the expression $5(B)$ is, well, profoundly wrong. I think what you're doing is taking the expression $n(B)$ and with $n=5$ and just substituting. Whoa, that's way off. $n(B)$ is the COUNT of observations in event $B$, i.e., the number of times event $B$ occurred in some sequence of observations. The $n$ in $n(B)$ has absolutely nothing to do with the sample size $n$. In $n(\cdot)$, the $n$ is part of the notation and can't somehow be stripped off.

Comment: @Did Thanks for this. I agree, your notation is better, I was just going by what the book said. I don't didn't necessarily drop the limit, I let the $n$ enter inside of the limit that was already there. The I observed that the limit could be broken up int0 $(\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty} n/n})(\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty} n(B)})$ where the first factor simply goes to one; and it is true that if the probability greater than zero for any event, then repeating the experiment infinitely many times should result in the event of interest occuring infinitely times.

Comment: @WillNelson  Let the experiment be rolling a six sided die. Then $S$ has 6 sample points. Let $B$ be the event that we roll a one, if we repeat this example 5 times the the relative frequency if event $B$ is $\frac{\text{number of time} B \text{ occurred}}{5}$ is might be nicer to write this as $5(B)/5$. $n(B)$ is a functions, we roll the dice if a one occurs, then we write a tally mark on your our notepad, at the end of $n$ rolls we add them all up and call this $n(B)$.

Comment: JimmyJackson, I see your point, but I'm pretty certain this notion $5(B)$ will be deeply confusing to almost anyone who sees it. It looks like you're multiplying $5$ and $B$. Strange. Instead, use the notation Did used: $N_n(B)$. The $N$ here means "count of" and the $n$ here means "sample size". In $5(B)$, you're really merging together these two very different ideas into the same part of the symbol. This would not be used in any careful, formal development. But I can tell you're thinking hard about this subject, which is good.

Comment: @WillNelson Thanks for the encouragement. I probably am over thinking this, but I personally demand that Mathematics be very consistent and self explanatory for myself. I very rarely will take something for truth unless it is clear to me first. This question comes from a small remark on pages 64-65 in Sheldon Ross's *A First Course in PROBABILITY* . If you have this book you might check it out and perhaps this question will make more sense, his approach seemed to lack a little rigor and I wanted to fill in the gaps. And, I will adopt the notation $N_n(B)$ from now on. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P(B)\ne0$ and $P(B)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{N_n(B)}n$ and $P(A\cap B)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{N_n(A\cap B)}n$ then
$$
P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{N_n(A\cap B)}n}{\frac{N_n(B)}n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{N_n(A\cap B)}{N_n(B)}.
$$

Comment: I had actually already shown this in my own work (not posted here)  but I was confused to whether I could interpret the final expression in the last equation as a relative frequency, since it was not being divided by $n$. However, steping back to the second to last expression clearly the numerator and the denominator are relative frequencies. I guess a Relative Frequencey (RF) divided by another RF, should be an RF.  Thanks for your answer
!